# covered exterior vents

Tags: repair

Builders covered 3 exterior vents for finished basement bathroom fan, laundry room fan and dryer. How do we find the I ended gent space and how can it be fixed with the least mess and inconvenience. This is two-year-new tract home.

Comment: What is an "I ended gent space"?

Comment: If the builder is still in business, call them up and say "Make this right!"

Comment: Are the vents close to the wall, the bath fan may be able to be accessed from the fan but I would agree with ecnerwal that the contractor should make it right.